# Creating intervals of 5 seconds for data and grouping them

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one column being time and the other column being price. it looks like this

```
Time     | Price
15:31:01 | 2
15:31:03 | 4
15:31:05 | 3
15:31:08 | 1
15:31:10 | 9
```

I would like to group the data in intervals of 5 seconds and take the average of each 5 seconds interval to look like this

```
Time     | Price
15:31:05 | 4.5
15:31:10 | 5
```

I know it is possible to do this via dplyr for grouping them in buckets of minutes where i extract the minute data for each row and then group them by minutes. But is there any way to do this for a custom second interval? In this case i am looking at 5 second interval.

Comment: How is the mean 4.5 in first interval? Shouldn't it be 3 ? (2 + 4 + 3)/3

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you or clarify if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the `Time` column to `POSIXct` format and `cut` it into intervals of "5 secs" and use that as a group and take `mean` in each group

```
aggregate(Price~ group, transform(df, 
    group = cut(as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%T"), breaks = "5 secs")), mean)

#                group Price
#1 2019-09-17 15:31:01     3
#2 2019-09-17 15:31:06     5
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Time = structure(1:5, .Label = c("15:31:01", "15:31:03", 
"15:31:05", "15:31:08", "15:31:10"), class = "factor"), Price = c(2L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```